# How to Remove dotted that appears when button is clicked

Tags: css

I'm using IE9 when i clicked a button appears dotted line,Please suggest how to remove that dotted lines.

Comment: outline:0; will do what u want

Comment: `a { outline: none; }` is the simplest css that works, replace `a` with the type of your button.

Answer (score 5):

For Internet Explorer 9 you can use this:

```
a:active, a:focus { 
 outline: none; 
 ie-dummy: expression(this.hideFocus=true);
}
```

I hope this will help you ........

Comment: Anchor tag is not wrapper around button,input bottom of type submit

Answer (score 3):

```
<input class="button" type="submit" id="submitForm" value="SEND" /> 

input[type="submit"] {
    outline: none;
    }
```

or

```
<input type="button" id="submitForm" value="SEND" /> 

input[type="button"] {
    outline: none;
    }
```

should work

Comment: Anchor tag is not wrapped around button

Comment: ah sorry do you mean an input button?

Comment: replace "submit" with "button"

Comment: <input class="button" type="submit" id="submitForm" value="SEND" /> i tried but its not working

Comment: I think we have slightly confused each other, check my edited answer again please, should be clearer.

Comment: When i clicked that button dotted lines will appear

Answer (score 3):

The css that seems to remove the dotted outline from inputs and buttons in Internet Explorer 8 and 9:

```
:root input:focus, :root button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

I found this by viewing the source of the outlook.com sign in page.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I wish browsers would not implement by default. I always use the following to reset the dotted line:

```
a:active,
a:focus,
input:focus {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me `a:focus, *:focus{ outline:none; _noFocusLine: expression(this.hideFocus=true); text-decoration: none; }`