# How to remove dotted border around radio button labels when they are active?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Remove dotted that appears when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393044/how-to-remove-dotted-that-appears-when-button-is-clicked)

I have some code like this:

```
<input id="input-radio-principal" type="radio" name="chart-type" value="principal" checked="checked" />
<label for="input-radio-principal">Principal balances</label>

<input id="input-radio-payments" type="radio" name="chart-type" value="payments" />
<label for="input-radio-payments">Monthly payments</label>
```

Whenever I click on a radio button, there is a gray dotted border on the radio button's label in IE9.  Is it possible to remove that border?

I have seen a lot of information about how to remove this from links, but not radio button labels.

Comment: not tested but maybe you could use javascript and call blur() whenever a radio button is clicked? So in jQuery: `$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){$(this).blur();});` or if it is on the label instead of using $(this) select the label `$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){$(this).next().blur();});`

Comment: That's an accessibility feature built into the browser.  You may be able to find a hack to remove it, but you probably shouldn't

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps this in your CSS:

```
input {outline: none;}
```

Works in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTrYf/5/)

Works in IE8 and IE 9, where the border isn't around the button or the label.  However, the border remains around the label in IE7.  I believe a full solution will probably involve Javascript, as the commenter above suggested.

Comment: Not working in my page

Answer (score 2):

```
<input class="button" type="radio" id="radioButton"/> 

input[type="radio"] {
    outline: none;
}
```

That should work in IE9